# Convert jQuery.parseXML Value to HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, regex

Need to convert some XML I'm receiving into HTML quickly.  Do I need to bust out RegEx?

Comment: if the "xml" is actually html, you can just pass it to `$`. What does the xml look like and what needs to be edited?

Comment: If you've parsed the XML already, regular expressions are not the framework for a solution. You have to traverse the constructed XML DOM and generate HTML according to your needs. Without knowing specifics of course it's impossible to suggest more.

Comment: `$.parseXML("<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>");` per the docs returns a **Document** object.  How do I work with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If XML contains data structure then use jQuery templating feature. This way you can define representation of each record/data structure in HTML. Along with jQuery if you use javascript MVC framework like AngularJS or Knockout you can convert your XML datastructure into HTML with minimal and maintainable code.

Example of jQuery Templates with KnockoutJS http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

If XML contains HTML elements then you it would be easy for you to write XSL and do the conversion from XML to HTML. Javascript engines have XSL processors that can convert XML to HTML using XSL templates

Introduction to client-side XSLT for XML to HTML conversion: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp